# BackHandler's HardwareBackPress event gets triggered on every screen of the navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using `BackHandler` on the "home" screen of my app to alert confirmation to the user to exit the app. I've 2 sets of screen Authentication and Home on my root navigator and `isLogged` bool determines which set gets shown.

Problem: The first render of the app works fine(be it Auth or Home set of screens) but when `isLogged` is changed and the set of screens changes, `BackHandler` starts triggering on every screen of the changed set. This is only fixed after restarting the app. Working example - https://snack.expo.dev/@msaxena92/11fd51

Expected result: Pressing back inside a navigator should take you to the `initialRoute` or first screen of the navigator and only after that when there are no more screens in the navigation stack it exits the app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have 2 options:

Use the [`useFocusEffect`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) hook instead of `useEffect` which will make sure that the effect is run only when you're on this screen:

```js
useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to exit?", [
        { text: "Cancel" },
        { text: "Yes", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() }
      ]);
      return true;
    };

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      "hardwareBackPress",
      backAction
    );

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, [])
);
```

Alternatively, you can also check for focus inside the effect:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  const backAction = () => {
    if (!navigation.isFocused()) {
      return false;
    }

    Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to exit?", [
      { text: "Cancel" },
      { text: "Yes", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() }
    ]);
    return true;
  };

  const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
    "hardwareBackPress",
    backAction
  );

  return () => backHandler.remove();
}, [navigation]);
```

Also see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-android-back-button-handling/

Comment: Thanks! This works. I knew screens stay mounted in a navigator but how come the first set of screens works fine( or after a restart)? It should also pop up on every screen before changing `isLogged`  right? Do correct me if I'm missing something

Comment: I don't think that should make any difference. Probably something specific in your app.